# uwsgi.cache_set() not working in separate thread inside a mule process

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, caching, uwsgi

For experiment, I set up a cache *`uwsgi.cache_set('test', data)`* inside a mule process. The cache is set as expected.

Now I spawn a thread from which I can access that cache

---

Threading is enabled in `uwsgi.ini`:

```
[uwsgi]
threads = 4
```

---

in `mule.py`:

```
#Threaded function
def a_function():
    uwsgi.cache_set('test', b'NOT OK') <- Nothing happens here
    cache_return = uwsgi.cache_get('test') <- Returns b'OK' which means the cache did not overwrite the previous value.

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cache = uwsgi.cache_set('test', b'OK')  <- Works here
    cache_return = uwsgi.cache_get('test') <- Return b'OK', as expected
    t = Thread(target=a_function)
    t.start()
```

The question is why does this happen and how do I set caches from inside a thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK it seems like I used the wrong function (`cache_set`) instead of `cache_update`.

> `uwsgi.cache_set(key, value[, expire, cache_name])`
>
> Set a value in the cache. **If the key is already set but not expired,
>   it doesn’t set anything**.

---

> ```
> uwsgi.cache_update(key, value[, expire, cache_name])
> ```
>
> Update a value in the cache. **This always sets the key**, whether it was
>   already set before or not and whether it has expired or not.